# I want to write a program that will operate and do things in another program

Tags: java, c

I am using this program called fin builder, and I want to write something, I am guessing in C or Java with which can perform basic tasks in fin builder. It would be like writing a program which could draw a face in photoshop. My question is which language should I use and does anybody have any tips on doing this, where should I start?

Thanks!

Comment: What you want is most probably impossible from the outside. Please take a look at the product you work with (fin builder) - they may have scripting capability. In that case you could use that to get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a code injection case. You would want to inject code inside a running process to make it do something.

I did it once with C# and with C++. But i'm sure you can do it with a lot of languages.
I must say though, it's not an easy process especially the first time you try to do this.

So choose your language and look around for code injection process with the chosen language.